# Spring Data procedure invocation

Tags: stored-procedures, spring-data

I have a procedure, which returns rows.
Each row has one column, which is a string, like so..

```
create procedure myproc(IN var1 varchar(255), IN var2 varchar(255))  
begin  
  select col3 from table1 where col1 = var1 and col2 = val2;  
end;  
/
```

I want to invoke this procedure using Spring Data.

The Spring Data manual says, I could invoke this procedure
from a method in a Repository, which is annotated with @Procedure
like so..

```
@Procedure(procedureName = "myproc")
List<String> myproc(String val1, String val2);
```

My question is.. how should the repository class, which will contain the annotated method,
be declared as

Should it be like this..

```
class MyRepository extends JpaRepository<T,ID>{
}
```

If yes, what type parameter should I use for T and ID
Should I necessarily create an entity class, to replace T above
If yes, what is a suitable type for ID in this case
And would I have to create a table in the database to hold this entity?

Answer (score 0):

Spring data jpa follows the `'domain driven design'`.
So I think it is mandatory to pass Domain.
Your domain is like

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    .... getter setter...

}
```

Your repository should be like below

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

    @Procedure(procedureName = "myproc")
    List<String> myproc(String val1, String val2);

}
```

1. You need to pass your domain class as T
2. You need to pass data type of `id` field of `Person` class as a `ID`, In this case it's a `Long`

For more info by example https://dzone.com/articles/calling-stored-procedures-from-spring-data-jpa